# AVPlayer doesn't play more than one time

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I have some strange problem with playing audio through AVPlayerItem & AVPlayer.

I have recorder and iPod item picker, stream from both of them are going through code like this:

```
  AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
  [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
  [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

  _playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:_soundFileURL];
  _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];
  [_player play];
```

Everything is actually ok, except one thing, I can't play this stream second or more time. It's just stopped, and no sounds are found after stopping. Does anybody can help with an advice, what the problem could be?

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the AVPlayer back to beginning of the stream using prepareToPlay and setting the currentPlaybackTime to 0.

```
self.avPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 0;
[self.avPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift 4**

You can use below line to play again.

```
self.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
self.player?.play()
```

**Happy to help :)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens on my Swift 5, Xcode 12, macOS 11, iOS 14.2 combination:

- I only play a short drop.wav sound for dropping a piece on game board
- a few months ago player.play() worked for my environment with lower versions
- today player.play() plays only once, dropping the next piece is silent
- adding player.seek(to: CMTime.zero) "works", but only the first time it sounds normal, the 2nd, 3rd ... time the sound is different, weaker
- my workaround is reloading the sound file every time before playing it
- I recorded a video for this experiment https://youtu.be/t6863IZkwTQ