# how add tap gesture to play a video player

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
videoPlayer = (AVPlayer.init(url: url as URL) as AVPlayer?)!

videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

var videoLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)

videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (pickVideo?.frame.width)!, height: (pickVideo?.frame.height)!)

pickVideo?.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

videoLayer.addSublayer((closeImage?.layer)!)

let tapGueturePlayVideo = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playVideo(sender:)))
tapGueturePlayVideo.delegate = self
tapGueturePlayVideo.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
pickVideo?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGueturePlayVideo)
pickVideo?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

And I have created function for Tapgesture here:

```
func playVideo(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    self.videoPlayer.play()

}
```

If long press and tap the video it plays smooth..If I tap out side the screen and tried to play another time it does not play..
Break point calls while tapping but player not playing

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the AVPlayer back to beginning of the stream using prepareToPlay and setting the currentPlaybackTime to 0.

> [AVPlayer doesn't play more than one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153476/avplayer-doesnt-play-more-than-one-time?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
videoPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 0
videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use `AVPlayerViewController` and `contentOverlayView`

Like that :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!
    videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    avPlayerController.player = videoPlayer
    avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width:200, height: 300)
    avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    self.view.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)

    let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.playVideo(sender:)))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    avPlayerController.contentOverlayView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}


 @objc func playVideo(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        self.videoPlayer?.play()

    }
```

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'AVPlayerViewController' facing this issue

Comment: just add `import AVKit`

Comment: I tried code in a sample project , single tap plays the video...But when I tap again the video does not play! How to fix this issue